# How to stop loading CKEditor Richtextbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor Richtextbox which i have placed below Gridview. In my grid view i have cascacading dropdowns, when i select 1st dropdown value causing postback event that time my Richtextbox get hidden for some sec and comes back and which causing extra loading to page.
Is there any way to stop this ?
Please suggest

Comment: Sounds like your dropdown is causing a full postback to the server, so your page reloads. Can you change your dropdown click to an AJAX call and prevent the postback?

Comment: @Atzmon 
There are some many dropdown with postback events , will cause lot of changes any other fix with same CKEDitor textbox so that We can stop this thing ?

Comment: When you post back the page reloads, there's no way around that. If you put the grid and dropdowns in an iframe, then only the internal page in the iframe will postback and reload, keeping the original page with the ckeditor textarea as they were, but this may be an architectural change that's also hard to implement in your specific application.